# Why we are required to install libraries each time in new npm project?

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code

Each time when I start a new project I download many dependencies and configure some settings in VS Code again and again. For example I run these commands like `npm install --save-dev webpack` and `npm install eslint --save-dev` and copy some config files like `.eslintrc`.

Is there any way to avoid this?

I use npm and VS code.

Comment: you could write your one script and use it as an CLI, to do things like this.

Comment: If you keep using the same or similar dependencies, you could also copy the package.json from an old project and use that as a baseline.

Comment: I can do that. But i want to find a way to have only one webpack file and use it in all project. In this way if webpak is updated only one file need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

the possible way is to delete the new node module folder and package.json from new installed project, and copy it from the old project.
there is no legal way to perform a new project without the installation of required packages through npm.